# Embedding image to menu item in Joomla with CSS

Tags: css, joomla

Could anybody help me to embed an image to menu item?

When I use (after) and (content) the image is displayed under the parent item, like this:

```
ul.jb_free_dropdown li.item-118:before { 
    position:relative; 
    float: right; 
    vertical-align: middle; 
    content: url(../../../../images/trianglegrey16x8.png)
}
```

How to display it in the same menu item and with float:right parameter?

Comment: Show some code. Why aren't you just putting `float: right` in your `:after { ... }` block?

Comment: `code`ul.jb_free_dropdown li.item-118:before
{
    position:relative;
    float: right;
    vertical-align: middle;
    content: url(../../../../images/trianglegrey16x8.png)
}

Comment: Alrighty, so what about that CSS isn't working? You need to be more forthcoming with information. It's almost like you don't want help

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm jumping here and there. The problem is that the float is working but I would like to put the image on the same level as the link text. With before the img is put ontop of the text and after takes it under.

Comment: Try not floating the pseudo element and giving it some dimensions. Try `inline-block`.

Comment: Ok with background the img isn't loaded. Or is it?

Comment: inline-block isnt helping much. Dimension are in another block for the whole menu. it just does not display as I want it to.

Comment: Without seeing you HTMl/CSS it's hard to diagnose but this might help: http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/LKzle

Comment: Hey it worked. Now tell me how to make it show only in parent item? 'cos it's showing on all child items too.

Comment: `#element ul:not(.jb_free_dropdown) li ....`